# cURL in PHP stops working after IP change

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I have a PHP script which downloads all of the content at a URL via cURL:

```
 <?php
 function get_curl_output($link)
{
    $channel = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10000);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10000);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.2) Gecko/20070219');
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $output = curl_exec($channel);
    if(curl_errno($channel))
    {
        file_put_contents('curlerror.txt', curl_error($channel) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    }
    curl_close($channel);
    return $output;
 ?>

 <?php
 function downloader($given_url){
     //download all the url's content in the $given_url.
     //if this $given_url is an array with 10 urls inside it, download all of their content. 
      while(as long as i find a url inside $given_url){
            $content_stored_here = get_curl_output($link);
            //and put that content to a file
      }
}
?>
```

Now every thing goes fine until there is no connection loss or IP changes.  However, my connection randomly gets a new IP address after some hours, as I don't have a static IP address.

And i use mod_php in apache using WinNT MPM thread worker.

Once I get the new IP address, my code stops working, but throws no errors

EDIT :

i made the same program on c++ (of course changing some functions name and tweaking compiler settings and linker settings)  c++ too stops at the middle of the programs once i got the new IP address or a connection loss.

Any insights on this?

Comment: You're not going to get much help if your purported code is an empty function with just comments.  Can you provide some actual code for us to look at?

Comment: How do you initiate your php script? Is it with a cronjob? Does the cronjob run the php in CLI or does it wget the php file? So I'm asking if Apache is involved...

Comment: Yes, it involves apache or should i use CGI ?

Comment: @cincodenada i added the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need such huge timeouts; when there is no connection cUrl tries to connect for as long as 10000 seconds accroding to your code. Set it to something more reasonable - just 10, for example

Comment: you are understanding the point here !! after a connection loss it is not working script just stops..